# How can I sync the calendars of Outlook.com and Outlook 365

Tags: calendar, office365, outlook.com

Is there a way to sync my Outlook.com (personal email address) calendar and my Outlook 365 calendar (work address) in a way where I can see the contents of Outlook 365 in my Outlook.com calendar?

Comment: Just add it as another mail account and both will appear in the same calendar.

Comment: @DavidGolding I have, and the email part works correctly but not the calendar part. Are you absolutely sure that this works?